# Can't open Facebook App through code?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to open the facebook App from my App. If the FB App is not installed it will open the page in the browser. When i click the facebook button nothing appears.I added some log's to know where the code stops but I can't find the Error ?

Here's my code

```
public class About extends MainActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{
    Button fb;
    static String TAG = "remote it";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, null, false);
        mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);
        fb = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.fb);
        fb.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Entered try ");
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/1473553"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/apauz"));
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.fb)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "fb is clicked");
            getOpenFacebookIntent(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
06-01 06:35:10.640: D/ExchangeService(1232): Received deviceId from Email app: null
06-01 06:35:10.640: D/ExchangeService(1232): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
06-01 06:35:11.600: D/remote it(1456): fb is clicked
06-01 06:35:11.600: D/remote it(1456): entered method
06-01 06:35:11.610: D/remote it(1456): try  clicked
06-01 06:35:15.669: D/ExchangeService(1232): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
06-01 06:35:15.679: D/ExchangeService(1232): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
06-01 06:35:15.679: W/ActivityManager(815): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-01 06:35:15.689: D/ExchangeService(1232): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-01 06:35:15.699: W/ActivityManager(815): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-01 06:35:15.699: D/ExchangeService(1232): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd9010 that was originally bound here
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd9010 that was originally bound here
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-01 06:35:15.719: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232): null
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd9010 that was originally bound here
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-01 06:35:15.759: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 06:35:15.759: W/ActivityManager(815): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4111d050
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd8c68 that was originally bound here
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd8c68 that was originally bound here
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-01 06:35:15.769: E/ActivityThread(1232):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232): null
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd8c68 that was originally bound here
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-01 06:35:15.819: E/StrictMode(1232):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 06:35:15.829: W/ActivityManager(815): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f44170
06-01 06:35:15.849: D/dalvikvm(1232): GC_CONCURRENT freed 450K, 20% free 2471K/3060K, paused 5ms+8ms, total 115ms
06-01 06:35:16.459: E/ThrottleService(815): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the `Intent` that you are creating.

In your onClick method, you have:

`getOpenFacebookIntent(getApplicationContext());`

which returns an Intent. But an Intent is just a description of an operation to be performed.

You need to actually trigger that operation by calling startActivity():

`startActivity(getOpenFacebookIntent(getApplicationContext()));`